# Memory and time efficient competition of correlation between each column in a large matrix and a vector

Tags: r, memory, matrix, correlation, memory-efficient

This question extends [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40141738/is-there-a-fast-estimation-of-simple-regression-a-regression-line-with-only-int), relating to a `machine learning` `feature selection` procedure where I have a large matrix of features and I'd like to perform a fast and crude `feature selection` by measuring the `correlation` between the outer product between each pair of features and the response, since I'll be using a `random forest` or `boosting` `classifier`.

The number of features is ~60,000 and the number of responses is ~2,200,000.

Given unlimited memory perhaps the fastest way to go about this would be to generate a `matrix` where the columns are the outer products of all pairs of features and use `cor` of that `matrix` against the response. As a smaller dimension example:

```
set.seed(1)
feature.mat <- matrix(rnorm(2200*100),nrow=2200,ncol=100)
response.vec <- rnorm(2200)

#generate indices of all unique pairs of features and get the outer products:
feature.pairs <- t(combn(1:ncol(feature.mat),2))
feature.pairs.prod <- feature.mat[,feature.pairs[,1]]*feature.mat[,feature.pairs[,2]]

#compute the correlation coefficients
res <- cor(feature.pairs.prod,response.vec)
```

But for my real dimensions `feature.pairs.prod` is 2,200,000 by 1,799,970,000 which obviously cannot be stored in memory.

So my question is if and how it is possible to get all the correlations in reasonable computation time?

I was thinking that perhaps breaking down `feature.pairs.prod` to chunks that fit in memory, and then do `cor` between them and `response.vec` one at a time will be the fastest but I'm not sure how to automatically test in `R` what dimensions I need these chunks to be.

Another option is to `apply` a function over `feature.pairs` which will compute the outer product and then `cor` between that and `response.vec`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's pretty similar in the sense that the most reasonable solution is my first suggestion in breaking down the feature.pairs.prod matrix to chunks and looping over them. Is there an R way to figure out the chunk size from my system's resources ,given feature.mat, though?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, chunk-wise computation is the way to go. This is also similarly done in [Out of memory when using `outer` in solving my big normal equation for least squares estimation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39839655/4891738).

The steps need not be changed:

```
set.seed(1)
feature.mat <- matrix(rnorm(2200*100),nrow=2200,ncol=100)
response.vec <- rnorm(2200)

#generate indices of all unique pairs of features and get the outer products:
feature.pairs <- t(combn(1:ncol(feature.mat),2))
j1 <- feature.pairs[,1]
j2 <- feature.pairs[,2]
```

But then we need to break `j1` and `j2` into chunks:

```
## number of data
n <- nrow(feature.mat)
## set a chunk size
k <- 1000
## start and end index of each chunk
start <- seq(1, length(j1), by = k)
end <- c(start[-1] - 1, length(j1))

## result for the i-th chunk
chunk_cor <- function (i) {
  jj <- start[i]:end[i]
  jj1 <- j1[jj]; jj2 <- j2[jj]
  feature.pairs.prod <- feature.mat[,jj1] * feature.mat[,jj2]
  cor(feature.pairs.prod,response.vec)
  }

## now we loop through all chunks and combine the result
res <- unlist(lapply(1:length(start), chunk_cor))
```

---

The major problem is how to decide `k`.

As demonstrated in the linked answer, we can calculate memory footprint. If you have `n` rows and `k` columns (chunk-size), the memory cost for a `n * k` matrix is `n * k * 8 / 1024 / 1024/ 1024 GB`. You can set a memory limit on entry; then since `n` is known, you can solve `k`.

Have a check on the memory costs for function `f`: `feature.mat[,jj1]`, `feature.mat[,jj2]` and `feature.pairs.prod` all need be generated and stored. So we have memory size:

```
3 * n * k * 8 / 1024 / 1024/ 1024 GB
```

Now suppose we want to constrain memory footprint under `4GB`, given `n`, we can solve `k`:

```
k <- floor(4 * 2^30 / (24 * n))
```